# In Azure Active Directory application for a client, what should my redirect url be?

Tags: azure-active-directory

I'm connected to a client's AAD to get access to their CRM, but am struggling with authentication. One part of this is the redirect_url. Is there a standard practice for choosing one? I see a lot of examples that say to use http://localhost, but wouldn't that just redirect to their own servers and now my own? It didn't work, regardless.

When trying to test with Postman, I read somewhere to use msal{{clientId}}://auth as the redirect_url, but this also didn't prove useful. I have my own personal website I could use, but is there a best practice for redirect_url when connected to another organization's AAD account?

Comment: Redirect URL is something where your client application will receive the token. Let us say your client app is running with the address of `https://example.com`, then the redirect URL could be anything like `https://example.com/login`, etc. This is the location where Azure AD will send the token response for the just authenticated identity. And `http://localhost` is used when you are testing the client app locally.

Comment: Got it, thank you for that explanation. If you want to submit that as an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redirect URL is something where your client application will receive the token. Let us say your client app is running with the address of `https://example.com`, then the redirect URL could be anything like `https://example.com/login`, etc. This is the location where Azure AD will send the token response for the just authenticated identity. And `http://localhost` is used when you are testing the client app locally.